# Limit number of lines shown in a textbox, but not limiting the user to write

Tags: html, css

I have a case I am not sure how to figure it out.

I am trying to do a design to put a button over a textbox, to make my layout looks nice, but when users start typing information in textbox, it hides behind the button. I know I have 1 of 2 solutions, but I don't know how to do it:

1- either to find another way to do the layout.

2- limit the number of lines for the user to enter, but this way I am going to have a restriction for long data.

Below is my HTML and CSS:

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}
.nl-main{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header{
  padding: 3px;
}
.header span{
  color: white;
}
.nl-txt-main, .nl-btn-main{
  display: inline-block;
}

.nl-btn-main .nl-btn{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  left: -50px;
    position: relative;
}

.nl-txt-main .nl-txt {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
    <span>Search our database</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nl-controls">
     <div class="nl-txt-main">
       <input type="text" class="nl-txt"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nl-btn-main">
      <input type="button" value="Send" class="nl-btn"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the button to be like part of the textbox itself, When you try to run the code, and write a long sentence in the textbox, it will hide under the button. How do I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `left:-50px;` from you button

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}
.nl-main{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header{
  padding: 3px;
}
.header span{
  color: white;
}
.nl-txt-main, .nl-btn-main{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

.nl-btn-main .nl-btn{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  left: -4px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin:0;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nl-txt-main .nl-txt {
  width: 200px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  margin:0;
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <span>Search our database</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nl-controls">
     <div class="nl-txt-main">
       <input type="text" class="nl-txt"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nl-btn-main">
      <input type="button" value="Send" class="nl-btn"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want the button to be as part of the textbox